# I m trying to fetch data from database and the while loop is keep on iterating unable to find the outcome help me to get rid of that

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a **Connect.php** file for connection to database. I also created a **php.ini** file.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']= '1';

include 'db/connect.php';
include 'func/articles.php';
include 'func/like.php';
?>
```

Also an article file to get specific data from database and table:

**article.php**

```
<?php

    function get_articles()
                {

                include 'core/db/connect.php';
                    $articles = array();
                    $quere="SELECT article_id,article_title, article_likes FROM articles";
                    $query = mysqli_query($con,$quere);
                     while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))!== false )
                        {
                        $articles[]=array(
                                            'article_id'    =>$row['article_id'],
                                            'article_title' =>$row['article_title'],
                                            'article_likes' =>$row['article_likes']
                                            );

                        }  
                        echo '<pre>'.print_r($articles, true).'</pre>';

                }   

?>
```

and finally use a **index.php** file for calling them both:

```
    <?php
        $articles = get_articles();
        if(count($articles)==0)
            {
                echo "Sorry! There are no articles";
            }
            else
            {
                echo'ul';
                foreach($articles as $article)
                    {
                    echo '<li><p>',$article['article_title'],'</p><p><a href="#" >Like</a></p></li>';
                    }
                echo'</ul>';
            }

        ?>
```

It's not working, and it's sending me error as:

> **Allowed memory size of
>   134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes)**

I really didn't get where the problem exist.

Comment: Is it me, or did you forget to do `return $articles;` in the get_articles() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write `while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))) {...`
as shown in [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#example-1668).

Also, remember to write a `return $articles;` in the `get_articles()` function.

Comment: Ya It work but the query for while loop is

while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))!= false )

Comment: @ManishNegi I think you are confused with your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to

```
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)))
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your script put this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

It will take unlimited memory usage on server.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is in the code where condition of while loop is incorrect  instead of**

```
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))!== false )
```

**we have to use**

`while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))!= false` )

and

> In article.php

**where i use**

```
 echo '<pre>'.print_r($articles, true).'</pre>';
```

**I have to use**

```
return $articles;
```